# htaccess Rewrite URL based on TLD

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

On my website, I am interested in moving my forums from a subdirectory to a subdomain. The forums are currently located at `example.com/forums`, and I want to move them to `forums.example.com`. After the move, I want to use htaccess to 301 redirect all forum traffic to the subdomain, but the problem is that I have two TLDs for my site, a `.com` domain and a `.net` domain.

I am currently trying to redirect traffic using this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=forums.example.net
RewriteRule ^forums(/(.*))?$ https://forums.example.net/$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=forums.example.com
RewriteRule ^forums(/(.*))?$ https://forums.example.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

This only half-works. Regardless of which TLD I visit, it always redirects me to `forums.example.net`, even if I am visiting from `example.com/forums`, in which case I want it to go to `forums.example.com`. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this **singe rule** as very first rule in **`forums/.htaccess`** instead of top level .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.(?:com|net))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://forums.%1/$0 [L,R=301,NE]
```

For root .htaccess use this rule as **your first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.(?:com|net))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forums(/.*)?$ http://forums.%1$1 [NC,L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is there anyway I could use the root htaccess file though? I'd like to avoid the need to have the directory actually exist if I can avoid it.

Comment: I am currently on the road and cannot access my web server, but I quickly tested it with [this htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) and it appears to be working.

Comment: I just tried it on the live server, and it's working! The only change I had to make was changing `http://forums.%1/$1` to `http://forums.%1$1` in the last line because the slash was causing two slashes when the subdomain redirection occurred to a page other than the index.

Comment: Yes good catch as I had an extra `/` before `$1` in updated rule.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below rules for the proper redirection to work as you want it.

```
Rewritengine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^forums$ http://forums.example.com/? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net$
RewriteRule ^forums$ http://forums.example.net/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but only if the URL is just `example.com/forums` or `example.net/forums`. If the URL has anything after `forums`, even if it is just a slash, the redirect does not work.

Comment: Never mind, I think I figured it out! I was able to get it to work by replacing both instances of `RewriteRule ^forums$` with `^forum/?(.*)$`.

Comment: Actually, that didn't work I'm afraid. I thought it did, but it didn't. When I tried it on a computer that didn't already have it cached, I got a 404 error.